# Cannot update and upgrade system

Tags: apt, 20.04

So, as you can see on the screenshot that that system cannot get update the list of PPA. How do I fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wait for the process to end and release the lock. Is you internet working fine by the way?

Comment: Yes, my internet works fine, this bug is working on Wayland only, by the way.

Comment: Do you use Kubuntu ? Packagekit is part of the KDE software suite.Looks like it's installing a software or updating them.Open the application **Discover** to find out what's going on.

Comment: @Kulfy It's not related to the network at all.Packagekitd is a KDE daemon for the application [Plasma Discover](https://userbase.kde.org/Discover) which acts like the software center.It's possibly installing some software or updating them because it has held the apt lock.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I believe packages or the repository cache whichever is being downloaded in the background directly depends on the network. If the network is facing issues, it'll probably take more time to release the DPKG lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find out if packagekitd is active is to see what resources it's using.
Use htop to locate it. If you don't have it:

```
sudo apt install htop
```

If it's inactive, zero cpu and memory consumption, and this goes on for too long, kill it and try again, one command at a time (for a better idea of what's happening):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install -f
```

I would do that in your place, risking to break packages.

Hope I have helped :)